# MySQL - count inner join query

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have the following query that works like i want it to, except i want to return a pseudo (?) column of the count of the number of units each property has that are matched from the inner joins. Where p.team = u.team and u.deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and u.rates != '0'.  Could i do this in the same query?

A property has several units. They are all attached to a "team"(think username).

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.title, p.state, p.city, p.regionID, p.team, p.type, p.lat, p.lng, p.url_title 
        FROM Properties AS p
        INNER JOIN Units AS u ON p.team = u.team
        INNER JOIN Rates AS r ON p.team = r.team
        INNER JOIN Photos AS ph ON p.team = ph.team
        AND p.public   = '1'
        AND u.rates   != '0'
        AND p.deleted  =  '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        AND u.deleted  =  '000-00-00 00:00:00'
        AND r.deleted  =  '000-00-00 00:00:00'
        AND ph.deleted =  '000-00-00 00:00:00'
        GROUP BY p.id
        ORDER BY p.created ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only have one aggregate and you seem to be grouping by the `Properties` row, this should be relatively easy. You mean something like this (untested)?

```
SELECT p.title, p.state, p.city, p.regionID, p.team, p.type, p.lat, p.lng, 
       p.url_title , COUNT(u.*) AS number_of_units
FROM Properties AS p
INNER JOIN Units AS u ON p.team = u.team
INNER JOIN Rates AS r ON p.team = r.team
INNER JOIN Photos AS ph ON p.team = ph.team
AND p.public   = '1'
AND u.rates   != '0'
AND p.deleted  =  '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
AND u.deleted  =  '000-00-00 00:00:00'
AND r.deleted  =  '000-00-00 00:00:00'
AND ph.deleted =  '000-00-00 00:00:00'
GROUP BY p.id, p.title, p.state, p.city, p.regionID, p.team, p.type, p.lat, p.lng, p.url_title
ORDER BY p.created ASC
```

Depending on what you mean, you might have to do `COUNT(DISTINCT(u.id))` instead. It is hard to tell from your question.

---

For reference, the "hard way" is to create a subquery to join against to do the count. You may need to do this to count multiple unrelated items, or to group by one thing and count by another:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.title, p.state, p.city, p.regionID, p.team, p.type, p.lat, p.lng,
                p.url_title, uuCount.number_of_units
FROM Properties AS p
INNER JOIN Units AS u ON p.team = u.team
INNER JOIN Rates AS r ON p.team = r.team
INNER JOIN Photos AS ph ON p.team = ph.team
AND p.public   = '1'
AND u.rates   != '0'
AND p.deleted  =  '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
AND u.deleted  =  '000-00-00 00:00:00'
AND r.deleted  =  '000-00-00 00:00:00'
AND ph.deleted =  '000-00-00 00:00:00'
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT uu.team, COUNT(*) AS number_of_units
    FROM Units uu
    WHERE uu.deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    AND u.rates != '0'
    GROUP BY uu.team
) AS uuCount ON p.team = uuCount.team
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.created ASC
```